# What does 'xing' in adsotrans dictionary mean?

Tags: dictionary, notation

I have downloaded the Adsotrans Chinese-English dictionary add-ons on Pleco,
and when I search for 松茸 this came up.
Other result may annotate translations as noun, adj, verb etc. but I have never seen this before. What does `XING` here mean?

I found a post on [pleco forum](https://plecoforums.com/threads/beta-5-bug-report-feedback-thread.1369/page-3#post-8661), but no one seems to address it either.

[image]

I also exported the [adso database](http://adsotrans.com/downloads/), and there are words that has `XING` annotation.

[image]

Comment: 形容詞 (xingrongci)? Maybe they forgot to convert it to ADJT?

Comment: oh, thats possible, but let me check for another occurrences of `XING` in the database to make sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to "adjective", from the Chinese word [形容词](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%BD%A2%E5%AE%B9%E8%AF%8D) (**xíng**​róng​cí​) = "adjective":

> Unit: Adjective
>
> - NOTE: this category covers adjectival noun [compound] headers    (ie. definitions that are commonly paired with nouns in compound   form).
>   **What are conventionally considered "adjectives" in the    English
>   language are classified by the system as Xingrongci    (ie. Xing).**
>   Compound elements containing Xing may be considered    Adjectives in
>   terms of their functionally in Chinese grammar. For    algorithmic
>   purposes, this category can be considered a low-confidence   form of
>   Xingrongci.
>
> Unit: Xing
> <sub>David Lancashire, [adso](https://github.com/wtanaka/adso), GitHub.</sub>

So this dictionary has both "Xing" and "Adjt".  As far as I'm aware, this usage is unique to this dictionary.

Comment: didn't know theres a git repo for that!